# Form filter - Unsupported lookup 'gte' for FloatField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-filter

I'm trying to make a FormFilter.

I have in my model something like:

```
class TabelaPreco(models.Model):
    [...]

class TabelaPrecoItem(models.Model):
    [...]
    preco = models.FloatField()
    tabela_preco = models.ForeignKey('TabelaPreco', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='itens')
```

.

My FormFilter:

```
class TabelaItemProdutosFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    preco__gte = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_expr='gte')
    preco__lte = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = TabelaPrecoItem
        fields = ['preco__gte', 'preco__lte']
```

And when I fill the inputs and search I get the following error:
Unsupported lookup 'gte' for FloatField or join on the field not permitted.

I didn't find anything that can helps me. I already tried to use NumericRangeField, but I don't know how to put it in 2 different inputs on template.

.
.

Edit:
I think the problem is in my queryset. I changed my model above.

```
form_filter = TabelaItemProdutosFilter(request.GET, queryset=tabela_preco.itens.select_related('produto', 'produto__modelo').filter(produto__saldo__gt=0).order_by('-produto__codigo'))
```

Where tabela_preco is the objects of my model TabelaPreco

Answer (score 0):

What I am sure of is that you can use `__gte` and `__lte` filters on  FloatFields. I don't know what the other possibility "join on the field not permitted" means. I usually code my filter fields using the more powerful representation, for example

```
fields = {
    'desc__ft':['gte','lte','exact'],
    ...
}
```

which results in three filters on the Float field `ft` on the object accessed via the foreign key field `desc`.

Are declarative filters and entries in `fields` mutually exclusive? You seem to be telling it to create the same two filters in two different ways.

Comment: It returns the same error when I try to apply only one of these filters :(

If I just use preco = django_filters.NumberFilter() it works, but I don't want that.

Thanks.

Comment: I changed my question. I think the problem is on the join.